# Dual-booting Ubuntu on a MBP with burning a disc

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 16.10

I know it is possible to dual-booting a MBP with Ubuntu 16.10 through the etching method of a disc. As I don't have a disc to burn, I was wondering if it is possible to install Ubuntu 16.10 without using this method. Could anyone be able to tell me if it is possible and how?

Thanks for your help!

**P.S.** I don't want to use the virtualization method, but rather the dual-booting.

Comment: If you don't have a disc to burn, you can either obtain one, or just install Ubuntu using a USB stick (instead of a DVD). https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop has instructions for both ways

Comment: @NickWeinberg Can an external drive can do the job instead of a USB key?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, as long as you're willing to lose everything that's on it!

Comment: Why lose everything that's on it? I could partition my external drive.

Comment: Because I don't think that's possible when making a Ubuntu USB installation disk... it uses the whole device, not just a single partition

Comment: I have a 2TB external drive. In that case, I think it is possible to partition my ED and use that partition to install Ubuntu.

Comment: I agree it's possible to partition it, but then when you turn it into an Ubuntu USB installer, you will lose **all** data from **all** partitions on the drive (Rufus or dd or whatever you use to make it an Ubuntu install disk takes over the boot sectors and redoes the partition table). I really don't want to debate this; if you still want to try it anyway, please first back up everything in two other locations before you attempt it, so you don't permanently lose all your data. You've been warned!

Comment: Do you really not have a spare USB drive with at least 2 GB of space lying around or one whose content you can back up elsewhere during the Ubuntu installation? They're like 5 $/€/£ in supermarkets (I presume you have these around based on your user name). I made a Live USB for myself with multiple partitions, but it wasn't easy because I couldn't find a reliable source for instructions and I'm still not sure what exactly did the trick. I also didn't have any valuable data on the drive while tinkering with it.